# WPF Multibuilding 2 Values to the same Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a table, and when the user would like to mark a row. he can click on button and mark it.
so I wrote a converter for the property, that if its true it return color(yellow)
and if false it return white,
however it Deletes the default style when user select a row in the table.

I was thinking of using Multibuilding once for mark, and one for selected.
however I am not understand what the syntax should be in WPF.

attaching the code I wrote,
will appreciate a code examples.

WPF:

```
    <Style TargetType="syncfusion:GridCell" x:Key="ComCell">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding COMPort , Converter={StaticResource CVconverters }  }" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding isBookMarked, Converter={StaticResource BookMarkConverter}}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

C#:

```
public class BookMarkConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valStr = value.ToString();
        
       
            if (valStr == "True")
            {
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {

            }
       

        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `Brushes.White` from the converter, you could return `Binding.DoNothing` from the converter if you simply don't want to change the background.

You could also base your `Style` on the default one:

```
<Style TargetType="syncfusion:GridCell" x:Key="ComCell"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type syncfusion:GridCell}}">
```